# How can i clone more than one git repository. If its possible?

Tags: git

we have an multiple git repository. how can i clone multiple repository at a time?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, possible, but not in the same directory.

You would have to [`git clone`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-clone) each repository in its own directory on your local disk.

See [How do you clone a git repository into a specific folder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/651038/how-do-you-clone-a-git-repository-into-a-specific-folder); one option:

```
git clone git@github.com:whatever folder-name
```

---

This is not to be mixed up with [`git remote`](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-remote.html), which allows you to declare several remotes from which you can [git fetch](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-fetch.html) (and then merge in your current git repo)

Comment: I really should downvote for providing a much too comprehensive answer, OP requested a single word ;-)) (just kidding, +1 from me)

Comment: he he.. me too, but another +1 from me.. :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible. Just do `git clone` in two different directories with two different repositories.