# Clone contents of a GitHub repository (without the folder itself)

Tags: git

I'd like to `git clone` the contents of a repository I have on [GitHub](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GitHub). When I `git clone` (git@github:me/name.git...) I get a folder called `name/` and inside name I have my contents... How do I get JUST the contents?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you clone a git repository into a specific folder?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/651038/how-do-you-clone-a-git-repository-into-a-specific-folder)

Comment: To actually skip downloading unneeded objects to save network resources: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/600079/how-do-i-clone-a-subdirectory-only-of-a-git-repository/52269934#52269934

Answer (score 407, accepted):

If the current directory is empty, you can do that with:

```
git clone git@github.com:me/name.git .
```

(Note the `.` at the end to specify the current directory.)  Of course, this also creates the `.git` directory in your current folder, not just the source code from your project.

This optional `[directory]` parameter is documented in the [`git clone` manual page](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-clone), which points out that cloning into an existing directory is only allowed if that directory is empty.

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesnt work if there are other, non related directories already in the same dir.  Looking for a solution.  The error message is: "fatal: destination path '.' already exists..."

Comment: The directory git clones into must be empty

Comment: what is git@github.me? Is it the path of the repository?
It's not working for me.
I am trying this and I want only files inside Test folder...
git clone https://github.com/humaun21/Test.git

I want to get only the files inside Test folder. But It's not working. I creates a Test folder which contains my folder. But I want only files inside Test folder?

Comment: @HumaunRashid Add a `.` as discussed in the answer: `git clone https://github.com/humaun21/Test .` . And yes, `git@github.me/name.git` is a placeholder for whatever your actual git repo address is.

Comment: @JohnLittle Had the same problem, turns out there is a hidden .DS_Store file, that hides there. Simply `rm .DS_Store` and you're good to go.

Comment: If you are working on linux OS, you need to be sure the directory is empty including checking for hidden files and subdirectories. You can do that with ls -a. You should have only . and .. as output. This wont work otherwise

Comment: if you remove the `.git` file in the folder you wish to directly move the sub-directories and files of the repo it will work
this error `"fatal: destination path '.' already exists...` is caused by the `.git` file which was probably created when you attempted the git clone without the `.`

Answer (score 183):

Unfortunately, this doesn't work if there are other, non-related directories already in the same dir. Looking for a solution. The error message is: "fatal: destination path '.' already exists...".

The solution in this case is:

```
git init
git remote add origin git@github.com:me/name.git
git pull origin master
```

This recipe works even if there are other directories in the one you want to checkout in.

Comment: Hey in this I am getting an error like Permission denied <public key>. The remote end hung up unexpectedly.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `github.com` there after `git remote ...`, and not just `github`?

Comment: This answer should have been accepted one. works perfectly.

Comment: I read elsewhere here that you need to run `git fetch --all` before the `git pull origin master`, because if there are other branches on the repo, `git pull` won't get those unless you use `fetch` first. Is this correct?

Comment: But then the other non-related directories and all their files will show up as untracked changes.

Comment: Folks might be landing here after the master -> main switch on GitHub. If so use `git pull origin main` instead as the last step.

Answer (score 48):

If the folder is not empty, a slightly modified version of @JohnLittle's answer worked for me:

```
git init
git remote add origin https://github.com/me/name.git
git pull origin master
```

As @peter-cordes pointed out, the only difference is using https protocol instead of git, for which you need to have [SSH keys configured](https://help.github.com/articles/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/).

Comment: What version of git are you running? This didn't work for me. It still won't let me set it up because the dir isn't empty

Comment: @guribe94 git version 2.5.0

Comment: This is the same answer, just using anonymous https instead of git-protocol over ssh (requiring a github account with an ssh keypair set up).

Answer (score 24):

You can specify the destination directory as second parameter of the `git clone` command, so you can do:

```
git clone <remote> .
```

This will clone the repository directly in the current local directory.

Comment: This works only if current directory isn't empty.

Answer (score 3):

to clone git repo into the **current** and **empty** folder (no `git init`) and if you do not use ssh:

```
git clone https://github.com/accountName/repoName.git .
```

Answer (score 1):

this worker for me

```
git clone <repository> .
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this question is old but please notice that `git pull` will abort if there is local files that matches the remote one, a solution for that would be to make a reset after pulling like this:

```
git init
git remote add origin REMOTE_REPO_URL.git
git pull origin master
git reset --hard FETCH_HEAD
```