# Clone a Git repo into the current folder (not a new subfolder)

Tags: git, gitbox

FYI I am running MAMP on OSX.  The remote repo is fine.  I have cleared out the .git folder and .gitignore file from my local directory however as I was having problems with it.  Here is the problem I currently face:

1. If I do git init in my local folder, then later add the pointer to the original master, it will not synch up - takes for ever and just hangs.
2. If I do git clone https://me@bitbucket.org/myrepo.git then it creates the git repo in a subfolder of the same name - not what I want.
3. If I do git clone https://me@bitbucket.org/myrepo.git in the parent folder (above myrepo) then it tells me it can't because destination path 'myrepo' already exists and is not empty.

How do I use git to say "hey, rebuild the .git and .gitignore file into **THIS FOLDER**, and let's start over again?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Github clone contents of a repo (without folder itself)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6224626/github-clone-contents-of-a-repo-without-folder-itself)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this:

```
git clone https://me@bitbucket.org/myrepo.git .
```

note the trailing `.`.