# How do I set up git clone one of my repositories

Tags: git, github, emacs

I have an Emacs Configuration in a repository and whenever I do `git clone <repository>` it creates for me a folder with the name of the repository and the configuration files inside

I would like it to only create "clone" the settings files instead of creating a folder with the files inside

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Clone contents of a GitHub repository (without the folder itself)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6224626/clone-contents-of-a-github-repository-without-the-folder-itself)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there are 3 options:

1. Download the files without cloning the repository
2. [Clone contents of a GitHub repository (without the folder itself)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6224626/clone-contents-of-a-github-repository-without-the-folder-itself):

   - `git clone url .` - works only if the current directory is empty
   - `git init trick` - (see the link)
3. Configure Emacs to load the config file from a different location:

   - Based on [Is there a way to change the init.el location on startup?](https://www.reddit.com/r/emacs/comments/4416iu/is_there_a_way_to_change_the_initel_location_on/):

   > replace your ~/.emacs.d/init.el with this:
   >
   > ```
   > (setq user-emacs-directory "/path/to/git_repo/")
   > (load "/path/to/git_repo/init.el")
   > ```

   - https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/12881/how-do-i-set-a-different-location-for-the-dot-emacs-emacs-file-on-windows-7