# Cloning git directly into web root public_html

Tags: git, github

Using github, when I clone a repository it creates a subfolder with the name of the repository.

For example, if I do the following command in my web root:

```
git clone git@github.com:exampl/myrepo.git
```

...then there is a folder `public_html/myrepo/`

How do I approach cloning it directly into the root of `public_html` without the subfolder being created?

Moreover, is this the best approach for deploying, or should I be creating a symlink, for example?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
git clone git@github.com:foo/bar .
```

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/651038/how-do-you-clone-a-git-repository-into-a-specific-folder) question for more details.

Answer (score 5):

Clone into cwd:

```
git clone git@github.com:example/myrepo.git .
```