# Detect and pull all github branches

Tags: github

Can i detect all branches in my github repos?
I'd like to write a .sh script that loops thru the branches and pulls each one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`git fetch` will bring down all branches from the remote repo.  Note that it will not **pull** the branches, pull is fetch + merge, which is probably not what you want to do.

Comment: I need to detect and then pull each branch into a separate folder. Look at this post to see when I asked this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6803119/testing-previewing-github-branches-on-a-dev-server any comments welcome.

Comment: This might be what you're after then: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6270193/multiple-working-directories-with-git

Answer (score 1):

The github2 module for Python provides an API library with commands for listing the branches in a repo, see [this documentation](http://packages.python.org/github2/api/repos.html).

If Python isn't your thing, take a look at the [list of libraries](http://develop.github.com/p/libraries.html) for other languages.

Comment: Great. And here is the command. GET /repos/:user/:repo/branches