# Can I specify the folder name of a cloned repository on Github for Windows?

Tags: git, github, github-for-windows

Hi there~ I'm using Github for Windows and am trying to change the name that is automatically generated by Github.

Right now if I clone a repo called `program-utilities` it will automatically create a folder where I tell it to named `/program-utilities/`. This is normally okay except in the case of an SFTP server I have mapped to a local drive.

I'd like `program-utilities` to be written right to `/httpdocs/` so I can `git pull` changes on the server and have them go live without having to sort out what files have been changed.

What happens now is I get `/httpdocs/program-utilities/` which isn't quite right. Or I can have `/program-utilities/` sitting *next* to `/httpdocs/` but I can't just clone right into `/httpdocs/`.

Is there a way to do this using the `Github for Windows` program?

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of [How do you clone a git repository into a specific folder?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/651038/how-do-you-clone-a-git-repository-into-a-specific-folder).

Comment: Thanks. I was looking for an option with the github for windows program specifically, if possible