# Change the name of a git repository on the local machine

Tags: git, directory

I have a git repository in a remote repository named `site.git`. I want to create a local repository in a subdirectory `site/www/`. When I simply clone the repository to the `www` directory, I get `site/www/site`.

How can I set up my local repository without the extra directory?

Comment: Is the `site` folder included in the git repository itself?

Comment: try git clone git@github.com/name.git path/to/folder

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you clone a git repository into a specific folder?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/651038/how-do-you-clone-a-git-repository-into-a-specific-folder)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
cd site/www
git clone site.git .
```

Comment: The `.` here is a path value, meaning "this directory".

Answer (score 3):

A similar question has already been asked and there is the perfect answer:

[How do you clone a git repository into a specific folder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/651038/how-do-you-clone-a-git-repository-into-a-specific-folder)

---

I will give the simplest solution. Use the command:

```
git clone <repository> [<directory>]
```

Link to documentation: [git-clone](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-clone)