# How do I fetch a remote branch?

Tags: git, gitlab

I deleted my git folder unexpectedly. i was working in remote branch repository.
How can i pull my remote branch to my local?

Comment: What does ‘*remote branch repository*’ mean? If you deleted `.git` you can use `git init` and `git remote add`. If you deleted the whole repo, just clone again.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Clone all remote branches with Git?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/67699/clone-all-remote-branches-with-git)

Comment: @dkinzer I think you might have misunderstood. Read the first sentence of the question again.

Comment: @Biffen: ...hmm, it's still a duplicate imho: http://stackoverflow.com/q/651038/256854

Comment: @dkinzer *Maybe* of that second one. The question is too unclear to know.

Answer (score 7):

**If you still have the git repo:**

Just do

`git fetch origin`

followed by.

`git checkout -b <branch> origin/branch`

**If you've deleted the git repository altogether**
Then reclone the repository:

`git clone <repository-address>`

Then, follow the steps above to get other branches if they didn't get pulled in automatically.

Answer (score 0):

> I deleted my git folder unexpectedly. i was working in remote branch repository. How can i pull my remote branch to my local?

#### What to do?

1. Clone the repo again
2. Checkout the desired branches

   ```
   # Clone the repo
   git clone <url>

   # Checkout the desired branch
   git checkout <branch name>
   ```

If you still have the `.git` folder and you did not remove it - read how to get your code back here:
[How to move HEAD back to a previous location? (Detached head)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34519665/how-to-move-head-checkout-revert-reflog-reset/34519716#34519716)

Answer (score 0):

```
git checkout -b branch_name
git pull URL branch_name
```

Answer (score 0):

```
git clone -b <branch_name> <url>
```