# Git Clone default directory on Windows 7

Tags: git, github, windows-7-x64

I wanted to clone github directory from web locally on Windows 7. So I used following command -

```
git clone git://github address
```

I was expecting that it will get downloaded under current directory, which was `c:/windows/system32`.

The output of the command is as follows -

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>git clone https://github.com/Hvass-Labs/TensorFlow-Tutorials
.git
Cloning into 'TensorFlow-Tutorials'...
remote: Counting objects: 338, done.
rRemote: Total 338 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 338eceiving object
Resolving deltas:   0% (0/158)
Resolving deltas: 100% (158/158), done.
Checking connectivity... done.
Checking out files: 100% (96/96), done.
```

But the cloned directory is nowhere in the path. Absolutely nowhere in the system. I tried current directory, entire C drive and entire D drive. But no luck. The repository was huge so I don't want to try cloning again. :(

Can someone please tell me under which directory Git clone downloads the github directory on Windows 7?

Comment: I don't think you actually cloned anything, q.v. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/651038/how-do-you-clone-a-git-repository-into-a-specific-folder).  Please check the syntax for `git clone`. By the way, the default behavior of `git clone` is to clone into the directory from which you issue the command.

Comment: I have edited my question. This is my output. The command was successful.

Comment: That output indicates it created `C:\WINDOWS\system32\TensorFlow-Tutorials`.

Comment: but its not there :(

Comment: Aside: Why would you put this in `C:\WINDOWS\system32`? Seems like a strange, and possibly unsafe, place to put sample code.

Comment: I know the folder was wrong. But that was just till the completion of command. I was supposed to keep it in my D drive folder after downloading.

Answer (score 1):

By default, git clone in a subdirectory of the current folder and that has the name of the repository cloned.

Here it should be `C:\WINDOWS\system32\TensorFlow-Tutorials`.

If you want to clone inside the current directory, you should add a '.' to indicate that you want to clone in the current folder.

But the folder should be empty.

And also, it's a very bad practice that cloning in a Windows system folder than you try to do... Prefer cloning in your personal folder and add the folder in the PATH if needed...

Comment: Its not there in the above directory.

Comment: I know its a bad practice but I generally fire the same command in Ubuntu and it works. I then copy it to my preferred location. So wanted to do the same here. But not able to find it in that location. God knows where it has gone!

Answer (score 1):

Finally it worked with following command.

D:>git clone https://github.com/Hvass-Labs/TensorFlow-Tutorials d:\tensorflow
Cloning into 'd:\tensorflow'...
remote: Counting objects: 338, done.
remote: Total 338 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 338
Receiving objects: 100% (338/338), 55.66 MiB | 1.10 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (158/158), done.
Checking connectivity... done.
Checking out files: 100% (96/96), done.

So it seems it was lacking permissions in system32 folder. But then it should have thrown the error.