# How to git clone with specifying the destination directory without its project name?

Tags: git

I uses macOS and Ubuntu. I want to git clone a certain project `https://github.com/Project/project.git` to a specific directory `$HOME/git`. I saw this page: [How do you clone a Git repository into a specific folder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/651038/how-do-you-clone-a-git-repository-into-a-specific-folder), but it requires to explicitly specify its project name like: `git clone https://github.com/Project/project.git $HOME/git/project`. How can I git clone them without specifying its project name?

[Add1] If I git clone like: `git clone https://github.com/Project/project.git $HOME/git`
then I encountered `fatal: destination path '/home/paalon/git' already exists and is not an empty directory.`

[Add2] I want to clone git-managed projects under `$HOME/git` directory. I want to set the state `ls $HOME/git` shows like `project1/   project2/   project3/`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you clone a Git repository into a specific folder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/651038/how-do-you-clone-a-git-repository-into-a-specific-folder)

Answer (score 8):

> How do you clone a Git repository into a specific folder?

The git clone command can be used in the following way:

```
 git clone <url> <destination>
```

---

> fatal: destination path `/home/paalon/git` already exists and is not an empty directory.

This is due to the face that you already have folder with the given name `/home/paalon/git`.
Delete the "old folder" and clone again, this time add the desired path to your clone command

Comment: Sorry for my question is ambiguous. I want to clone git things under the `$HOME/git` directory. So I want to set like `ls $HOME/git` shows `project1/      project2/        project3/ `.

Comment: `git clone <url>  $HOME/git/project1` where project1 is your desired name

Comment: Yes. I know it but I want to do it without specifying the project name.

Comment: if you dont specify the name it will get the default name under **the current** directory where you run `git clone`

Comment: Yes, but I want to specify it from not the current directory.

Comment: So you must specify a name. Why not using a script?

Answer (score 2):

Split into 2 commands:

```
cd $HOME/git
git clone https://github.com/Project/project.git
```

That way you name the project only once.

Answer (score 2):

```
git -C $HOME/git clone https://github.com/someorg/Boostnote.git
```

will create `$HOME/git/Boostnote`

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that's actually correct. You can clone providing *any* directory as your target. It doesn't have to match the project name:

```
$ git clone https://github.com/eantoranz/bwv blahblah
Cloning into 'blahblah'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 221, done.
remote: Total 221 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 221
Receiving objects: 100% (221/221), 62.45 KiB | 480.00 KiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (150/150), done.`1
```

Comment: I get the following error:
`$ git clone https://github.com/BoostIO/Boostnote.git $HOME/git`

`fatal: destination path '/home/paalon/git' already exists and is not an empty directory.`