# Is there a way to open remote directories with all files in sublime text (Windows)

Tags: sublimetext, remote-access

I need to use the features like **find in folder** to search for contents inside remote directories, currently I must download the directory and do this locally, or visit files individually. Can anyone put something helpful for this?

This question is asked as a comment [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/651038/how-do-you-clone-a-git-repository-into-a-specific-folder) as well, but no answer is provided.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Search in directories seems to be possible with Linux commands if you have SSH access to the server, have a look at this question's answers: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16956810/how-do-i-find-all-files-containing-specific-text-on-linux

Comment: @Mohandes Thanks, you are right that is useful in Linux, but It will be more comfortable if there be any option to work with that locally.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the SFTP package [enter link description here](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/SFTP)

After installation, you need to set up a remote host.

`on your project right click > SMTP/SFT > MAP to remote`

in the opening window setup your host connection.

You need to just update this section.

```
"host": "example.com",
"user": "username",
//"password": "password",
//"port": "22",

"remote_path": "/example/path/",
```

then check your connection 
`Right click on sublime > SFTP/FTP > Browse Remote`

If you connect successfully you will see your directories.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks, and do we need to have a repository here? You said "on your project right click > SMTP/SFT > MAP to remote". So what if we don't have that project in our local?

Comment: no matter, It is just a start point. In my case, I start from another directory and the `sftp-config.json` created there, and I need to go to that directory and start the process, it is just the path of your config file.

Comment: If it being in the root direcotry you can access it in any subdirectory, but you can access it from any parent directory. SO it is good to config it for the root directory and just use it in any subdirectory.

Answer (score -1):

To to use the features like find in folder to search for contents inside directories I recommend firstly Notepad++ secondly visual studio community thirdly atom-git ;

if in chrome or firefox browser you can hit F12 developer mode and browse the dependent files in the folder structure remotely ;

even you access remote web resource your computer still need to download them anyway so you can download first to a temporary folder, use Notepad++ to "Find in Files" which is quite a powerful feature. The user interface is also visually appealing with fast execution of the directory wide search.

Comment: So what you mean is using npp we still need to copy those file temporarily, right?

Comment: we still need to copy those file temporarily ; but maybe if you wanted you could use the F12 web inspector on chrome to see the remote files and folders.