# Add destination folder when batch cloning git repositories using shell script

Tags: git, sh, xargs

I'm trying to clone a set of repositories from GitHub. It works but I can't work out how to add a destination folder with `xargs`. This is what I currently have

```
curl "https://api.github.com/orgs/$org/repos?access_token=$authToken" |
  grep -e 'clone_url*' | 
  grep -w clone_url | 
  grep -o '[^"]\+://.\+.git' |
  xargs -L1 git clone
```

Except I want the cloned repositories to go into a another directory `./my_folder`. I've tried changing the last line:

```
xargs -L1 git clone "./my_folder"
```

But this does not work. I can't work out how to add on the extra argument using `xargs`. The normal way would be to just add the destination folder on to the end of the command like in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/651038/how-do-you-clone-a-git-repository-into-a-specific-folder) but I can't quite work out how to do this with my code.

Comment: Can you try doing `xargs -L1 -I {} git clone {} "./my_folder"`

Comment: Thank you @Inian! That works perfectly. Do you want to make that an answer and I'll mark as correct?

Comment: @alaniwi: Please feel free to add an answer on that with your observations.

Comment: I've now added a separate answer (so have removed my comments above).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that the destination folder for each `git clone` operation needs to be a separate subdirectory of `my_folder`, whose name would probably be something like the basename part of the git URL.  This is probably hard to achieve using `xargs`, so I suggest in place of the xargs an explicit loop:

```
... | while read repo_url ; do git clone $repo_url my_folder/$(basename $repo_url) ; done
```

This to go at the end of the pipeline after the `curl` and `grep` commands.

You could of course strip off the `.git` if preferred, by replacing `$(basename $repo_url)` with

```
$(basename $repo_url | sed 's/\.git$//')`
```

Putting it all together for convenience:

```
curl "https://api.github.com/orgs/$org/repos?access_token=$authToken" | \
  grep -e 'clone_url*' | \
  grep -w clone_url | \
  grep -o '[^"]\+://.\+.git' | \
  while read repo_url
  do 
      git clone $repo_url my_folder/$(basename $repo_url | sed 's/\.git$//')
  done
```