# How to only git pull in particular folder from a repository using Jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-job-dsl

I have a folder inside D:/TestFolder/ Now I need to git pull inside TestFolder using Jenkins every time I trigger a job. How is it possible?

Can anyone guide me on Jenkins git pull in a particular folder?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you clone a Git repository into a specific folder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/651038/how-do-you-clone-a-git-repository-into-a-specific-folder)

Comment: No, I am asking how can I Do in Jenkins Application. I think that is not helping me. sorry!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

git plugins for Jenkins come with that option -

If you are using Jenkins freestyle job,
[image]

If you are using Jenkins scripted pipeline , It will be like

```
node() {
  stage('checkout') {
     checkout([$class: 'GitSCM', branches: [[name: '*/master']], doGenerateSubmoduleConfigurations: false, extensions: [[$class: 'RelativeTargetDirectory', relativeTargetDir: 'sub_folder']], submoduleCfg: [], userRemoteConfigs: [[credentialsId: 'credentialId', url: 'http://repourl.net/x.git']]])

  }
}
```