# After cloning, is name from the <repository> (e.g. repo.git) always equal to the name of the folder (e.g. repo)?

Tags: git

This is a theoretical question with the purpose to better know git.

After [cloning](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-clone), is name from the `<repository>` (e.g. `repo.git` has name `repo`) always equal to the name of the folder (e.g. `repo`)?

Example:

```
$ git clone ssh://xxx@xxx.yyy:2222/repo.git

# will the folder be _always_ named "repo"?
```

In other words: is possible to have `repo1.git`, which after cloning creates folder `repo2`?

Comment: [_"The "humanish" part of the source repository is used if no directory is explicitly given"_](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-clone#Documentation/git-clone.txt-ltdirectorygt)

Comment: You can clone to any directory you want, one way is: `git clone <url> ./`

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/651038/how-do-i-clone-a-git-repository-into-a-specific-folder

Comment: Study `git clone --help` (every git command has its own `--help`). It shows an optional `[<directory>]` as the last parameter. Git just makes the directory name same as the repo name without the `.git` at the end - but you can provide your own value for the directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If no additional arguments are given, the directory name will always match the repo name. You can specify a different [directory](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-clone#Documentation/git-clone.txt-ltdirectorygt) manually though:

```
git clone ssh://xxx@xxx.yyy:2222/repo.git my-super-project
```

From the documentation:

> The name of a new directory to clone into. The "humanish" part of the source repository is used if no directory is explicitly given (`repo` for `/path/to/repo.git` and `foo` for `host.xz:foo/.git`). Cloning into an existing directory is only allowed if the directory is empty.